# How do I check to see if a value exists in PropertyDataCollection?

Tags: c#, .net, wmi

I have a class which collects information from servers using WMI. The problem is that some versions of windows seem to have different properties available/missing and I cannot seem to find a way to check the collection to see if a value exists before I attempt to access their value.

To be clear, I have found it possible to loop through the entire collection and check each property name value by using wmiSingle.Properties.GetEnumerator() - but there must be a better way. Right?

```
ManagementScope wmiScope = new ManagementScope("\\\\MyLaptop\\root\\cimv2");
ObjectQuery wmiVolumeQuery = new System.Management.ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor");

using (ManagementObjectSearcher wmiObjectSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wmiScope, wmiVolumeQuery))
{
    using (ManagementObjectCollection wmiMany = wmiObjectSearcher.Get())
    {
        foreach (ManagementObject wmiSingle in wmiMany)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(wmiSingle["Name"]);

            //This line will throw an exception. How do I test to see if
            //  "SomeProperty" exists before attempting to access the value?
            //Console.WriteLine(wmiSingle["SomeProperty"]);
            object somePropertyValue = wmiSingle.GetPropertyValue("SomeProperty");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the only way to check this is to iterate through the Properties

```
foreach (var prop in wmiSingle.Properties)
{
    if(prop.Name == "SomeProperty")
    { /* do something */ }        
}
```

You could also just catch the exception - like this

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static object TryGetProperty(this System.Management.ManagementObject wmiObj, string propertyName)
    {
        object retval;
        try
        {
            retval = wmiObj.GetPropertyValue(propertyName);
        }
        catch (System.Management.ManagementException ex)
        {
            retval = null;
        }
        return retval;
    }
}
```

Intentionally / knowingly causing exceptions to be thrown is typically not efficient; however, neither is iterating through an entire collection looking for a single property.

Comment: I believe you are right, but I hope you are wrong. I'll give it another day then accept.

Answer (score 4):

In your specific situation I would store the names of all the properties in a HashSet and check against that. That is incredibly fast.
Especially if you are going to check more than once during the lifetime of your program.

```
HashSet<string> KnownProperties = new HashSet<string>() { };
```

Then once populate it in an iteration through the properties

```
foreach (PropertyData prop in mo.Properties)
{
     KnownProperties.Add(prop.Name);
}
```

Now you can get the value incredibly fast (I tested it and got 60 ticks for 100 iterations = 60ns!)

```
string Value = KnownProperties.Contains(PropertyName) ? mo[PropertyName].ToString() : "";
```